# SVN repo access over the web by Repo browser

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have published my SVN repository on server that are out of my domain for automated deployment. URL is being Opened and working through Internet Explorer. When I open the same URL in repo browser , **It failed. Why?**

Suppose

**My url is** 
http://IP Address9/svn/myproject

It prompts me for username and password in Internet Explorer

Username – Domain\username 
Password - Password123

If I do enter the same credentials in **Repo Browse**r , it rejects.. WHY?

I am using Visual SVN on server side and TSVN 1.7.x on Clinet. 
looking forward of your reply.

Cheers,

Comment: rejects how? What's the error message? What's in the apache error log on the server?

Comment: are you behind a proxy? Could be the case that IE has different proxy settings (for example automatically applied during login)...